# How to access secure MQ queue from stand-alone Java application

Tags: java, security, ibm-mq

I need to access a secure MQ queue from a stand-alone java application.

What different mechanisms are available to do so?  Where can I find details of the different ways it can be achieved?   Any code snippets or document links are appreciated.

Thank you

**UPDATE**

Thanks Shashi.

I am not too familiar with MQ. I am on java side, so I asked our MQ admin to help me explain.  This is what they told me, we have.

```
    We have a “secure” qmgr MGR1. We are attempting to secure all of the objects.

    We use two (or more) types of security.

    Object Level security and Channel Authorization records.

    Using Channel Authorization records, we can control who can use a channel 
    from where (userid / IP Address) – block everyone else.

    Object level security, controls who can access a specific object and what 
    they are allowed to do:

    UID1 has connect authority to the qmgr. Read authority on PV.** queues.
```

Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Can you please describe what you mean by secure MQ?

Comment: @Shashi - Thanks.   I Updated the question with details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Got it. It is all administrators job to

```
1) Allow you connect to queue manager
2) Allow you put/get messages to queue(s)
```

From the application point of view nothing related to security is required. Application need to write code to connect, send/receive messages. There are number of samples shipped with MQ. You can find them under Tools/wmqjava/samples folder on a Windows machine. There are both Java and Java/JMS samples. To start with you can look at `MQSample.java` sample.

**Edit**

Sample code for setting userID from application using `USER_ID_PROPERTY`

```
Hashtable props = new Hashtable();
props.put(CMQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "mymq.server.com"); 
props.put(CMQC.PORT_PROPERTY, 1414);
props.put(CMQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN");
props.put(CMQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "myusername";)

MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager, props);
```

Comment: Thank you.  Will I need to install MQ client on my windows box? Our MQ is on linux.  Will the code exist on linux, so tha tI can ask the admins to give me access to the directory?  Also, I am able to do JMS with non-secure queue.  Will the samples have code for accessing the secure queue?

Comment: There is nothing specific required in your code.  You need to install the MQ client on windows box. The samples cover a range of languages including SSL. From your answer, the qmgr has only basic security and doesnt use any SSL or custom channel exits which challenge for a user/password authentication. Just make sure, whatever SVRCONN/CLNTCONN channel you are using to connect to the qmgr has U1D1 as MCAUSER.

Comment: Thank you. I worked with the MQ admins. They set-up the security on the channel / queue based on IP address, because when I made the call using stand-alone application, it did not send my user id as the user who invoked the java process. 

Is there any way I can send the Id from my application, so that they can make the security wotk with Id making the call instead of allowing anything from a given IP address have access to the object?